# Patch all containers in a Deployment with Kustomize

Tags: kubernetes, kustomize

I need to add volumes and related mount points to all containers of a deployment with Kustomize.

I'm trying json patch for that

```
 - op: add
   path: /spec/template/spec/volumes/-
   value: [...]
---
- op: add
  path: /spec/template/spec/containers/0/volumeMounts/-
  value: [...]
```

This will work only on one container (will somehow add it to the "2nd" container when there are 2 despite index `0`). This will fail if there is no existing `volume` or `volumeMount` with "doc missing value".

If I try to use regular patches, I need to specify the container name. Since I have 8 deployments with different container names, I'm looking for something flexible enough to avoid repeating the patch 8 times.

Kustomize docs shows an example to add a resource to multiple deployments here https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kustomize/blob/master/examples/patchMultipleObjects.md but that doesn't not cover adding one resource to multiple containers.